# Angular4 ngIf Uncaught Error: Template parse errors

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular-ng-if

I need help with the following if statement.
If c.name = 'Pipe Systems' then ng-template #PS should execute. 
If c.name= "Bathroom and Drainage" then ng-template #BD should execute.

I keep on getting "Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:". No matter what I try I just can't get the simple logic to work, I'm new to angular and I just can't get around this issue, if someone could please help me structure my ngIf correctly to simply filter the correct sub-category options when the main category options is selected. Below is my latest fail attempt.

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="category">Category</label>
      <select id="category" class="form-control">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [value]="c.key">
          {{ c.name }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="subcategory">Sub-Category</label>
      <select id="subcategory" class="form-control">
        <option value=""></option>
        <div *ngIf="c.name = 'Pipe systems'; then PS>
          <ng-template #BD>
            <option *ngFor="let s of subcategoriesBD$ | async" [value]="s.key">
              {{ s.name }}
            </option>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template #PS>
            <option *ngFor="let s of subcategoriesPS$ | async" [value]="s.key">
              {{ s.name }}
            </option>
          </ng-template>
        </div>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Database is as follows on Firebase:

[image]

Comment: `c.name = 'Pipe systems'` this is an assignment and not comparison, should be using `==` or `===` for strict comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be because of the `=`?, try:

```
<div *ngIf="c.name === 'Pipe systems'; then PS">
```

Comment: It compiles now, some small errors appearing but I should be able to resolve it now, thank you for the assistance, funny how an '=' can cause the world of problems, was 5 hours of frustration later.

Comment: I am currently struggling to access c.name in my if statement, is there a way to pass the variables inside {{ }} and store it in a global variable? Thank you. 

If I move the div into the ngFor it works but then simply displays the correct data under the option variables and I need it to display on the path below that.

<option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [value]="c.key">
     {{ c.name }}
</option>

Comment: For what you are trying to achieve it's better if you change the server response to send you a proper answer. Something like `{categoryA: {data: {}, subcategories: []}}`